# How to align image to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, imageview

I want to align my image to the bottom of the screen. As par my app conditions I have to set the scaleType of my image to matrix . and when I apply scaleType to matrix I really do not know Why My image to top. here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_capture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="content_desc_overlay"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_overlay"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="matrix"

            android:src="@drawable/suit_1"

            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/overlay_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            ></RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

now I am setting image in the ImageView id=iv_overlay which is supposed to be on the top of every view in the xml and that is working , iv_overlay Imageview is on the top but is set on the top left corner of the screen.

Where as it should be at the bottom of the screen. So please tell me How can I achieve this by setting scaleType , I know If i remove scaleType then it could easily be align to the bottom. But due to some reasons I have to use scaletype =Matrix.

Edit :
For those who want to see the image , here is the demo image , resolution is 
479*414  , But I am using this image given below is a demo image and will get soon the better image from the designer with transparent background

[image]
Please help.

Comment: can u please attach an image so i can exactly know what you want

Comment: what do you want ? Do you want to see how I want to align the image in the view?

Comment: show image of your layout

Comment: let me attach ,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Put your imageview inside relative layout. and use alignparrentbottom=true

Comment: use it android:gravity="bottom" instead of android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: its not working ? Have you implemented scaleType to matrix ever ?

Comment: let me down rate your answer

Answer (score 0):

your problem is

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

change both of these to "`wrap_content`" and your problem is solved

Comment: if I chaged it into a wrap content then the image can only be move to the layout it takes not the whole screen

Comment: change this only in iv_overlay

Comment: yeah I am talking about ivOverlay exactly

Answer (score 0):

For those people who are working onTOuchListnere and wants to rotate , zoom , and drag and using matrix as scale type and facing the similar problem As I did, here is a complete solution through java code

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                Rect rectDrawable = drawable.getBounds();
                float leftOffset = (imageView.getMeasuredWidth() - rectDrawable.width()) / 2f;
                float topOffset = (imageView.getMeasuredHeight() - rectDrawable.height()) / 1f;

//                Matrix matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
                 matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
                matrix.postTranslate(leftOffset, topOffset);
                imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

it would work like a charm